# IntelliJ fails to commit changes when attempting to sign commit (GPG)

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gnupg

I have been working on setting up my development environment, so when I create a commit it is automatically signed by GPG. I followed Githubs documentation on the matter here: https://help.github.com/categories/gpg/.

I am attempting to use IntelliJ's git interface to create a commit, but it always fails with this error.

> ```
> gpg: cannot open `/dev/tty`: Device not configured
> error: gpg failed to sign the data
> fatal: failed to write commit object
> ```

I do not encounter this error when using git directly from my terminal, I discovered an issue where someone had a similar problem (with Source Tree) and mentioned something about the GUI not popping up to enter passphrase. I'm assuming this is similar to that issue.

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Configure GPG to allow it to be called from a program remotely by adding the following to your `gpg.conf`:

`no-tty`

Comment: FYI this file is located in the home directory https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration.html

Comment: I also needed to set the Git config file with `git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following options in your `gpg.conf`

`no-tty`

`use-agent`

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the cause of this yesterday, and figured I'd post an answer for anyone else who might look at this. It was caused because when it tried to sign the commit, it wanted to open a window asking for my passphrase.

This was the tutorial I followed (specifically the bottom part so it wouldn't ask me in the future for the passphrase). https://github.com/pstadler/keybase-gpg-github

Note that the tutorial is for macOS only.

Comment: Hi, I still have the same problem in IntelliJ even though I used the same guide. Committing from console, or even inside the console of IntelliJ works fine and the commit is being signed automatically. But using the "VCS -> Commit Changes" dialog still throws the 'cannot open tty' error.

Comment: yep, I'm getting the exact same experience. still searching for a fix.