# gpg: signing failed: No secret key

Tags: git, gnupg

I cannot commit anything into my git repository anymore. I'm running Windows 11 and I'm trying to commit from VS Code version control panel. I'm just getting this:

```
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
```

I definitely have the correct secret key in my .gitconfig and gpg-agent is running. I've been trying to solve this for an hour and haven't been able to.

My `.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = Roni Nevalainen
    email = kitten@kittenz.dev
    signingkey = (signing key)
[core]
    editor = code --wait
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[color]
    ui = auto
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
```

Output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`:

```
sec   rsa4096 2020-12-19 [SC]
      (gpg key)
uid           [ unknown] Roni Nevalainen (kittenz.dev email) <kitten@kittenz.dev>
uid           [ unknown] Roni Nevalainen (GitHub key) <31485942+Cinderkittenz@users.noreply.github.com>
uid           [ unknown] Roni Nevalainen <catmaster.kissa@gmail.com>
ssb   rsa4096 2020-12-19 [E]
```

Comment: Can you show your `.gitconfig` and the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`?

Comment: @dan1st Here's my .gitconfig (GPG key removed, both are the exact same copy-pasted) https://gist.github.com/kittenz/9b7b224c97284ce872977c5ef4d0ba78. And `gpg --list-secret-keys`: https://gist.github.com/kittenz/663cf0ad6a884f97ff97a987c4453b04

Comment: Does the `(signing key)` in the `.gitignore` match the `(gpg key)` in the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`?

Comment: @dan1st yes, it does

Comment: You may want to configure the path for the gpg executable as shown by @[VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997768/10871900).

Comment: That did work! Thanks!