# The key whose key-id is in the signature did not sign this commit

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I'm trying to sign my git commits, but when I push them to GitHub they have the `Unverified` badge and

> The key whose key-id is in the signature did not sign this commit. Someone may be trying to trick you. GPG key ID: mykeyid

I find this quite cryptic, in my world the id with which a commit is signed will appear in the signature, as the key with that id signed the commit!

> **Question** How is this possible, and how do I solve it?

I especially want to be able to sign commits automatically from within my IDE, without needing to enter my passphrase every time.

---

If interested, here is a summary of the relevant steps I did. The first few coincide with GitHub's guide for signing commits.

1. Generate key pair, add GPG key given by `--armor --export` to GitHub account
2. Update git config with `user.signingkey`.
3. Set commits to be signed by default with `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`.
4. The gpg version that comes with git is too old, I installed gpg 2, checked with `gpg --version`, I updated `GNUPGHOME` just in case.
5. Made a script `C:\Users\username\gpg-no-tty.sh` and put into it `echo mypassphrase | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --batch --no-tty --yes "$@"`. Couldn't find anything better than a plaintex password.
6. Point git to this script with `git config --global gpg.program C:\\Users\\username\\gpg-no-tty.sh`.

**Verifications**

7. Important: I verified that `git verify-commit HEAD` shows the same ID as the `signingkey` in my git config which is the same as my GitHub GPG key shows in settings. (It also outputs a warning `gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir`)
8. Also important, as Ferrybig mentioned in a comment I checked that my email in my gitconfig is the same as used for my gpg key is the same as used as primary (verified) email in GitHub.
9. As Jens Erat mentioned in a comment, you can also use the fingerprint (40 character string) instead of the long id (16 characters) as outputted by `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG`, I tried this in my gitconfig but it didn't help.

---

#### gpg-agent

As Daniel H suggested in the comments there is something like gpg-agent which should remember your passphrase, and this is what I tried:

1. Add `use-agent` and `no-tty` (had something to do with my IDE not expecting a console interface asking for password) to `C:\Users\username\.gnupg\gpg.conf`, change `gpg.program` in my `.gitconfig` to `gpg`
2. Add to `C:/Users/username/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` the time to live: `default-cache-ttl 34560000` and `max-cache-ttl 34560000`
3. I get `gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session`, and didn't find yet how to solve it. Both `gpg-agent` and `gpg` are version 2.2.1 so that's not the problem.
4. According to some sources, for gpg version > 2.1 the environment variable `GPG_AGENT_INFO` needs to point to `C:\Users\username\.gnupg\S.gpg-agent`. I did this and rebooted. Now I get `gpg: gpg-agent protocol version 0 is not supported`.
5. I added `:1` to that path and now I get `gpg: can't connect to 'C': invalid value`. This doesn't make any sense to me. What is C and where does it come from? Is the my drive letter, so gpg tries to execute the path as an object?

Comment: This isn’t the main answer to your problem, but you might want to look into GPG agent. With it, you only need to enter your passphrase once, and GPG will remember it until you reboot the computer. It doesn’t have the problems of using a plaintext passphrase. With what you’re doing now, you might as well not use a passphrase at all, since anybody who gets at your private key file probably can read the script as well.

Comment: @DanielH It's true, a plaintext passphrase makes no sense but I didn't quite manage to get gpg-agent to work (see edit). I'm still searching for a solution, who knows it will solve the entire problem.

Comment: DOes the email you have used for gpg match the git email?

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes I forgot to mention but I checked that my email in my gitconfig is the same email as used for the gpg key and is the same email as my primary email for GitHub.

Comment: Do you have multiple keys with the same mail address on your computer? Are you referencing the key in your GnuPG configuration by key fingerprint or mail address? The mail address might be used in multiple keys (and thus you might select the wrong one), the key's fingerprint uniquely specifies a key. Also read up on [What is an OpenPGP Key ID collision?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837) considering the difference between short and long key IDs and fingerprints.

Comment: @JensErat No, I used to have two id's for my key but I deleted one (it didn't help). I'm referencing the key with the 16 character string as outputted with `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG`, as in [GitHub's guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/). That output used to show only one key, by now I have two but with different email addresses. Thanks for the link, I didn't know that! I used the long id everywhere, using the full fingerprint in my gitconfig didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either just put no passphrase on your key when you create it, or you can try gpg-agent. For me it didn't work, I still had to provide a passphrase but it's worth a try:

Update git to at least 2.19.1 because it includes gpg2 now, make sure you use git's gpg and try to use gpg-agent again - it should work now. Only step 2 of your 'gpg-agent' steps should be enough.

You might need to remove your `~\.gnupg` directory including keys if you run into migration problems (beware the error messages can be very misleading), so you can regenerate everything (including keys) using git's gpg.

I have written the complete instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884134/4126843).